# what does git pull origin [branchname] mean?

Tags: git

I am working on a branch of git, for example, the branch name is `branch1.1`. when I do

```
git pull origin branch1.1
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 10):

If you do a `git pull origin <remote branch name>`, it will fetch the remote branch and then merge it into your current local branch.

Comment: I think people will only understand this answer if they first understand that GIT maintains a local version of the origin branch. It fetches into that and merges that into the branch itself. Otherwise, they will wonder - merge what into what.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming little knowledge of Git functionality.

Git allows for parallel development to be going on. `master` is generally reserved for tested, finished production code that can be pulled in and used. Before developments are pushed they are first developed on a branch, in your case `branch1.1`. Branches allow for concurrent development, potentially with bugs while they develop, that can then be merged into the `master` when they're ready.

When you `git pull origin branch1.1` you are telling `git` to `pull` (technically `fetch`) from the remote repository you set up previously (`origin`) and specifically `pull` in `branch1.1` (instead of the `master`) and then run `merge` to integrate it into your local branch.

You can consult the git branch tutorial for more info: [3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)